# Build a Logic Pro audio unit to convert synthesizer output from 32 to 64 bit

Tags: audio, converters, core-audio

My friend is a musician and is needs to convert a Logic pro synthesizer output from 32 to 64 bit. I'd like to save him a good amount of money by writing the converter.

I'm wondering if anyone here who has worked with apple audio units can give me some guidance as to where I should start. I see there is an audio unit programming guide, but not really sure what needs to be done to write the converter.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Where does this "synthesizer output" have to go to? Do you mean the internal signal data representation having converted from Float32 to Float64? I don't know if Float64 signal format is supported in CoreAudio. There is a 32-bit and 64-bit API for Apple Software, but this doesn't have to do with signal format, AFAIK. Also, there are 32-bit and 64-builds of Logic Pro, nothing to do with signal format. If you just mean wrapping a 32-bit built  AU plug-in for use in 64-bit hosts, there are commercial apps which do it, I don't know a programmatic answer to it.

Comment: I suppose I did not fully understand what was going on. I am looking to wrap a 32-bit built AU plug-in for use in 64-bit hosts programmatically. Thanks for helping me articulate myself.

Comment: If you are still looking for an answer, perhaps it would be good if you could edit and re-phrase your question, rather than letting someone else edit it for you...